# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Trojan HEUR/QVM03.0.Malware.Gen

Tags: visual-studio-2015, malware, trojan

I created a very simple Windows form project in Visual Studio 2015, with only 1 button, that shows 1 message box on click.

I compiled it and sent the file the file to a friend, but he scanned it with [Virustotal](https://virustotal.com), where the result was [this](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8f554c0a6cb0de1368dd53e9afd6064e6942268b07e5584ebf92d6ec304e8ab1/analysis/1448884311/). One AV detects it as `HEUR/QVM03.0.Malware.Gen`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Ever heard of something called a false positive?

Comment: Yeah been google about it. Not 100% sure what that means. I have to say to my friend, hey dont worry about the malware, its a false positive? Sorry its the first time it happends to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Virus Total scans the uploaded file with a lot of different antivirus products. Some of these product are good, some are great, but some are also poor. This is the reason why some of these products will give a false positive on even a simple Windows Forms application.

Some antivirus vendors go as far as detecting any executable (*.exe file) as "malware" or "suspicious" if it does not have a digital signature. This is a very bad approach and a lot of independent developers have had problems because of this. It is easy for a big company which creates some commercial software to acquire and buy a digital certificate, which will be used to sign software, but this is very big problem for an independent developer working on a freeware app.

Comment: @abitguru You are welcome! Can you please mark the answer as accepted, if you found it useful ...

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this post, activating `Enable ClickOnce security settings` and setting the Build Configuration to Release will avoid all false positives. Of course, nothing stop Qihoo or another AV vendor to later naively flag all .EXE as malware.